# How to check to see if a certain line is found before a certain point in a txt file?

Tags: python

I need to figure out if a certain phrase/line is found before another phrase takes place in a text file. If the phrase is found, I will pass, if it does not exist, I will add a line above the cutoff. Of note, the phrase can occur later in the document as well.

An example of what this txt format would be could be:

```
woijwoi

woeioasd
woaije
Is this found
owijefoiawjwfioj
This is the cutoff

asoi w
more text lines
Is this found
aoiw
```

The search should cut off on the phrase "This is the cutoff". It is unknown what line the cutoff will be on. If "Is this found" exists before the cutoff, pass. If it does not, I want to add the phrase "Adding a line" right above the cutoff to the output doc.
An example of the code I've tried so far, with all strings previously defined:

```
     find = 'Is this found'
     with open(longStr1) as old_file:
        lines = old_file.readlines()
        with open(endfile1, "w") as new_file:
            for num, line in enumerate(lines):
                if "This is the" in line:
                    base_num = num
                for num in range(1, base_num):
                    if not find in line:
                        if line.startswith("This is the"):
                        line = newbasecase + line
```

I am getting an error for "name 'base_num' is not defined" Is there a better way to perform this search?

Comment: First of all add a full error trace, second this is indeed an invalid syntax. try `range(1, num)`. Also instead of doing two loops, wouldn't it be easier to do one loop which stops on the cutoff and searches for the `find` phrase at the same time?

Comment: Making the syntax edit you suggested, I get an error for that line: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'range'`. And yes, I am hoping to find a way to consolidate the code into one loop

Comment: sorry didn't see that `line` there... what you would want to do in that case is change the loop to `for line in lines[:num]` and then just `if not find in line`

Comment: The range is where I am trying to set the # of lines to search (having just defined num as the cutoff line) for the search term.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this? Looks for both find and cutoff index positions, then cycles through the line list and checks for the cutoff index, evaluates if there's a previous "find" variable and if not adds the "Adding a line" line and ends the new file.

```
find = "Is this found"
find_index = 0
cutoff = "This is the cutoff" 
cutoff_index = 0

with open(longStr1) as old_file:
    lines = old_file.readlines()
    if find in lines:
        find_index = lines.index(find)
    if cutoff in lines:
        cutoff_index = lines.index(cutoff)
    with open(endfile1, "w") as new_file:
        for num, line in enumerate(lines):
            if cutoff in line:
                if cutoff_index < find_index:
                    new_file.write("Adding a line\n")
                new_file.write(line)
                break
            new_file.write(line)
```